# How to access another user's data via the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Using the Graph API and related authentication/authorization flows, how can I access data of all users in an organization? Also, multiple organizations/tenants need to be able to use the app.

As an example: I have an app which needs to read events from all calendars of all users under contoso.onmicrosoft.com. I would like that jack@contoso.onmicrosoft.com, the administrator, authorizes the app which will then be able to read the mentioned the data. Using the Managed API this can be easily done via impersonation.

However, I am trying to do the same with Graph API and OAuth, but I can't find a straight forward solution, or I must be missing something very obvious. I have created an app through manage.windowsazure.com (multi-tenant), and configured it so that it requires Microsoft Graph API (all application and delegated permissions).

I did the following:

1) Point jack@contoso.onmicrosoft.com towards `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=<my redirect url>&client_id=<my client id>`

2) Jack authorizes the app

3) I get back: `<my redirect url>/?code=<my authorization code>&session_state=<blah>`

4) I send a POST request like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
Headers: content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body:
grant_type=authorization_code&code=<my auth code from step above>
&redirect_uri=<my redirect url>
&client_id=<my client id>
&client_secret=<my client secret>
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
```

5) When I do the following:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jack@contoso.onmicrosoft.com/messages
Headers: Authorization: Bearer <auth token from step #4>
```

I get a 200 OK response with the messages.

When I do the following:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/anyotheruser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com/messages
Headers: Authorization: Bearer <auth token from step #4>
```

I get a 403 Forbidden response with:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2016-06-07T08:47:27",
            "request-id": "5b629e30-e6bd-474d-b3dd-8ce25c5ad1c4"
        },
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow/URLs you've referenced are for the authorization code flow which leverages delegated scopes.

A) If you want the app to only work (i.e. access all calendars) for admins then you are using the right flow.

B) If you want the app to work for all users after the admin consents to it, you'll need to use the app (client credentials) flow and use application scopes. This means that you'll need to separate out consent from the regular auth flow.

For consent you'll need to to point the admin to the following url:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_id=<YourClientId>&client_secret=<YourClientSecret>&response_type=code&redirectUri=<YourRedirectUri>&prompt=admin_consent
```

For auth flow you'll need a single call from your web server:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
body resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_id=<YourClientId>&client_secret=<YourClientSecret>&response_type=code
```

Or better yet, just use ADAL's AquireToken(resource, clientCredentials) overload.

Once that's done, your app should be good to go to make requests to Graph.

Regardless if you want to stick to A) or switch over to B), to double check that things are set up correctly you can:

1. Check the token that you get back from Graph (the one you attach to the request along with Bearer) and confirm that it has a roles entry with the roles you need i.e. Calendars.Read

**NOTE**: The following steps 2.a & 2.b require you to have admin to a test tenant where you'd be consenting to the application.

2.a Use GraphExplorer (https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/) and confirm that consent has been properly set up by querying

```
beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq '[YourApplicationName]'
```

If nothing shows up, then the no one has consented to the application.

2.b (only applicable for auth code flow with delegated scopes) Use GraphExplorer and confirm that either delegation has been authorized correctly by querying

```
beta/oauth2permissiongrants?$filter=clientId eq '[IdFrom ServicePrincipal in 2.a]'
```

And ensuring you get either a result for the specific user in question or for "AllPrincipals".

---

More info on app vs delegated scopes here: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

More info on app flow here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only

Comment: This helped! I switched to the App Only version (had some problems with certificates, but in the end it worked out, without them). The key, looks like, was adding `prompt=admin_consent`, since I tried the flow before, but didn't work. I do have some issues with certain API calls, but there is a lot space of SO for such.:) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Please use the app-only auth flow (see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) to use the application permissions - for the token request (step 4) you need to pass grant_type=client_credentials instead of grant_type=authorization_code.